# GAE/P transaction using static method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions

I'm trying to figure out how to organize app engine code with transactions.  Currently I have a separate python file with all my transaction functions.  For transactions that are closely related to entities, I was wondering if it made sense to use a `@staticmethod` for the transaction.

Here is a simple example:

```
class MyEntity(ndb.Model):
    n = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

    @staticmethod
    @ndb.transactional # does the order of the decorators matter?
    def increment_n(my_entity_key):
        my_entity = my_entity_key.get()
        my_entity.n += 1
        my_entity.put()

    def do_something(self):
        MyEntity.increment_n(self.key)
```

It would be nice to have `increment_n` associated with the entity definition, but I have never seen anyone do this so I was wondering if this would be a bad idea.

MY SOLUTION:

Following Brent's answer, I've implemented this:

```
class MyEntity(ndb.Model):
    n = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

    @staticmethod
    @ndb.transactional
    def increment_n_transaction(my_entity_key):
        my_entity = my_entity_key.get()
        my_entity.increment_n()

    def increment_n(self):
        self.n += 1
        self.put()
```

This way I can keep entity related code all in one place and I can easily use the transactional version or not as needed.

Comment: Why use a static method, and in fact why even a class method? Also I hope you reload the instance, after calling self.do_something as the current self will be clearly out of date.  Your current definition of increment_n means any key (ie not a MyEntity key) could be passed in. Having said that I use classmethods all the time for factories etc... I don't see any value in the a staticmethod here though, as the functionality of increment_n seems very MyEntity specific.

Comment: Hi @TimHoffman, the reason I want to use a static method is that the transaction only ever operates on a certain entity type and I want the code for the transaction to be in the same location as other code relating to that entity.  My understanding is that I can't use a regular method (since we need to pass the key and not the entity) and using a class method here doesn't seem helpful since the transaction doesn't refer to the class.  Therefore I thought I would use a static method.

Comment: It looks like your method would make sense.  Let's flip this around: have you found a problem with this approach?

Comment: @BrentWashburne, I haven't tried it yet.  I'm nervous about stacking decorators since I'm a novice with them and not sure what the proper order is.  Was hoping to get some advice before jumping in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later came across the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108657/appengine-ndb-transactional-classmethod-decorator-order).  Here is a quote:

> A decorator would wrap the function it is decorating. Here, your
>   add_cost function is wrapped by ndb.transactional so everything thing
>   within the function happens in the context of a transaction and then
>   the method returned by that is wrapped by classmethod which returns a
>   descriptor object.
>
> So, when you apply multiple decorators in a class, then decorators
>   such as classmethod or staticmethod should be the top ones. If you
>   change the order you would receive an TypeError: unbound method ....
>   type of error if the other decorator doesn't accept descriptors.

So it looks like the order of decorators is very important.  By luck, I had put mine in the right order, but updating this for others who come across this question.

Comment: You are right, and I have updated my answer accordingly.  Though the original question was about whether it made sense to use `@staticmethod` at all (the order of decorators was a side question).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it makes sense to use a `@staticmethod` in this case, since the function doesn't use a class or an instance (`self`).

And yes, the order of decorators is important, as noted in @Kekito's later answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've now tested it and it seems to work well.