# Appengine NDB transactional classmethod Decorator Order

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to update some properties of an NDB model transactionally, and it seems sensible to make the update function a classmethod:

```
class Thing(ndb.Model):
    cost=ndb.IntegerProperty()
    @classmethod
    @ndb.transactional()
    def add_cost(cls, thid, amount):
        thing=cls.get_by_id(thid)
        thing.cost+=amount
        return thing
```

This is used thus:

```
# Add 25 to cost
thing=Thing.add_cost(thing.key.id(), 25)
```

Does it matter which order the decorators appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the order of decorators does matter. From the [PEP 318 -- Decorators for Functions and Methods](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax):

> The rationale for the [order of application [16]](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-September/048874.html) (bottom to top) is that it matches the usual order for function-application. In mathematics, composition of functions `(g o f)(x)` translates to `g(f(x))`. In Python, `@g @f def foo()` translates to `foo=g(f(foo)`.

In your case it would translate to:

```
classmethod(ndb.transactional(Thing.add_cost(...)))
```

A decorator would wrap the function it is decorating. Here, your `add_cost` function is wrapped by `ndb.transactional` so everything thing within the function happens in the context of a transaction and then the method returned by that is wrapped by `classmethod` which returns a [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods).

So, when you apply multiple decorators in a class, then decorators such as `classmethod` or `staticmethod` should be the top ones. If you change the order you would receive an `TypeError: unbound method ....` type of error if the other decorator doesn't accept descriptors.

You can also refer to following post for more details:

[Why can @decorator not decorate a staticmethod or a classmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6208458/2549021)